# Dyncrypto - ASP

Tags: asp, componentes

Tenho um site que estava em um servidor e agora passou para um novo.
Ele tem um trecho de código onde usa o componente Dyncrypto

```
Set DynCrypto = server.CreateObject("DynCrypto.Crypto")
```

Eu instalei o componente no servidor novo e passou dessa linha de código.
Ao chegar nessa linha:

```
PublicKey = DynCrypto.AsymPublicKey(PrivateKey)
```

Ele dá erro 500. Descobri que ele dá problema porque não tem a licença.

Alguém sabe como instala essa licença? Pedi uma de teste por 30 dias mas não consigo registrá-la.

Comment: Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Instalação da licença

Uma licença possui duas informações: "Owner" e "Key". Estas informações devem ser armazenadas em um arquivo chamado LICENSE.INI, localizado na pasta onde está o arquivo DYNCRYPTO.DLL.

**1)** Abra o Bloco de Notas

**2)** Copie e cole no Bloco de Notas o texto abaixo, alterando as informações da licença (`Owner` e `Key`) conforme o seu caso:

```
--- begin of  file ---

[License] 

Owner = 30 Days Evaluation
Key = KKkNLxYEj6VXd1WEF9+fvrXA4yAPvtpz7vSHFWnGNn8=

--- end of file ---
```

**3)** Salve o arquivo com o nome LICENSE.INI na mesma pasta onde está o arquivo DYNCRYPTO.DLL

Mais informações você encontra no **[manual do desenvolvedor](http://www.dyncrypto.com/Installation.htm)**.